# It might sound silly but why using frameworks like jersey in REST webservices in android?

Tags: android, rest

I am very new to android and webservices.At first I saw only aynctask with http methods to retreive data from databases.I thought anything with http methods are rest.Now Iam seeing frameworks like jersey to do REST based webservices.What is the purpose of these frameworks?.Cant we do rest webservice in basic level?

PS:Sorry if question is too blunder.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. The framework is doing it as well under the hood. If you feel the framework helps you to achieve your goals faster and with cleaner code use it, otherwise don't. Typically, frameworks support more advanced features like object marshalling, caching or asynchronous calls and can help with error handling.